# Can someone explain this website speed test result?

Tags: performance, pagespeed

I have taken over the management of a site - [Expand in the USA](http://www.expandintheusa.com). The site loads far more slowly than would be expected given its content and the fact that it has been optimized. When I run a speed test using [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/), I find that the bottleneck is the time that it takes to connect with the server (as highlighted in this [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/09b48i5z29)). I am relatively inexperienced with this type of issue and was hoping someone might be able to suggest the root cause so that I can work on resolving it.

Comment: The server is taking several seconds to render the front page. Once that's done it seems OK. You can: reduce the content; increase the server performance; optimise the code. It's a Wordpress site so the last option might not be practical. This isn't a programming problem so it's probably off-topic here. You could check out [webmasters.se]

Comment: No, there is no issue with the time to connect. Fixing website performance is really difficult and you clearly have a lot of learning to do first. And you are running on Wordpress which makes it even worse. Unless you want to take a year or two out to learn about WPO, maybe you should hire an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of pingdom you please check with http://gtmetrix.com/ .Gtmetrix will give you exactly what is the problem.Try to install Pagespeed in your server which really helps to improve the performance and you will fell the difference even.